# Consume liferay internal services from android client

Tags: android, liferay

I am a biginner with liferay, I want to develop an android application can connect to my liferay portail. I need a login, profile information and user documents screens on android devices. So, I need to get all the necessary data from my liferay portail. Please give the simple way to do this task.
Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here some two good starting points:

[Liferay Screens](http://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-screens/overview)

[Liferay connector for js cross platform](https://github.com/smclab/liferay-connector)

Comment: thank you for your response Daniele. I check out the lifreay-screnns project from github but I want know how to get the list of user documents when he login for examlpe.

Comment: Every Liferay portal exposes REST Json service to query all the portal data, you can try locally using http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws 
See this guide http://www.liferay.com/it/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/JSON+Web+Services